# Mobile and Wear module does not communicate with each other in my app

Tags: android

I am using a sample code for `wear` and `mobile` to communicate with each other, the code working fine(`wear` sends notification to `mobile` and vice versa) when I create a new project and paste the sample code in the new project.

I have integrated a `wear` module in my `Android` application,  because I eventually want to add wear support. Now I copy and paste the sample code in my project that to send notification from wear to mobile and vice versa, but the code does not work in my project.

Please guide me that what I am missing in my project due which I am facing the issue. Your help and support would be really appreciated in this regard.

The following are files of my `project`.

```
Wear module code


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

    <activity
        android:name=".views.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".views.activities.MyConfirmation" />


</application>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, MessageApi.MessageListener {

    //Google Api Client and Node
    private GoogleApiClient m_googleApiClient;
    private Node m_node;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {

                //Get the send button
                Button sendBtn = (Button) stub.findViewById(R.id.bt_send);
                sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        sendMessage("Message from Watch!");
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        m_googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        m_googleApiClient.connect();



        /*Button buttonStart = findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sendMessage("Message from Watch!");

            }
        });
        // Enables Always-on
        //setAmbientEnabled();*/




    }

    private void sendMessage(final String s){

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                if(m_node != null){
                    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
                    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(m_googleApiClient, m_node.getId(), "WatchToPhone", bytes).await();
                }

            }
        }).start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(m_googleApiClient).await();
                List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                if(nodes.size() > 0)
                    m_node = nodes.get(0);
            }

        }).start();
        Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(m_googleApiClient, this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't Connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        if(messageEvent.getPath().equals("/PhoneToWatch")) {

            Log.e("Watch", "data rec");
            //Send a success message to the screen
            Intent success = new Intent(this, MyConfirmation.class);
            success.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE, ConfirmationActivity.SUCCESS_ANIMATION);
            success.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Hi Phone Message to Watch");
            startActivity(success);

        }
    }

}
```

Here is the mobile module code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileSdkVersion Integer.valueOf(project.TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"



        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        //Step-1: Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    //This added for WorldPay gateway
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$project.BUILD_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$project.BUILD_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$project.BUILD_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$project.BUILD_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$project.BUILD_VERSION"

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    wearApp project(':wear')

    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.4'

    //Step-2: Enabling multidex support.
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


    //For In-App purchases
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myproject">

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Needed only if your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />


    <!-- Declaration for Bluetooth Security permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Declaration for Internet connectivity -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



    <!-- For In-App purchases -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">
        <activity
            android:name=".views.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>



        <service
            android:name=".location.CurrentLocationByGoogleApiClient"
            android:stopWithTask="true" />

        <service
            android:name=".location.FetchAddressIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />



        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity android:name=".views.activities.WatchTestActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>



public class WatchTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, MessageApi.MessageListener{

    private GoogleApiClient m_googleApiClient;
    private Node m_node;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_watch_test);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initCommunication();
            }
        }, 1000);

        Button buttonSend = findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendMessage("Hello");
            }
        });
    }

    private void initCommunication() {
        m_googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        m_googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        //Toast to indicate connected
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Get the node of the watch
        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){

                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result = Wearable.NodeApi
                        .getConnectedNodes(m_googleApiClient).await();
                List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                if(nodes.size() > 0)
                    m_node = nodes.get(0);

            }

        }).start();

        //Set the Message Api Listeners to this class
        Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(m_googleApiClient, this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //Connection Failed toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        //Check the message and toast if its the correct message
        if(messageEvent.getPath().equals("WatchToPhone"))
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Message from Watch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void sendMessage(final String s) {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                if(m_node != null){
                    Log.e("WatchTestActivity","Message Send");
                    byte[] bytes = ("wew lad".getBytes());
//                    byte[] bytes = (s.getBytes());
                    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(m_googleApiClient, m_node.getId(), "/PhoneToWatch", bytes).await();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```